# Extracting motion vectors from H.264 bitstream

Tags: video-compression, motion-detection

I'm looking for an open-source tool/code or some guidance to extract the motion vectors (MVs) of a H.264 encoded bit sequence. I'm already aware that motion vectors can be visualized using ffmpeg with the following command:

`ffplay -flags2 +export_mvs input.mp4 -vf codecview=mv=pf+bf+bb`

However, I want to produce a log file where the MVs of P and B frames are listed frame by frame. I checked out the structure of MVs from *libavutil/motion_vector.h*, but I couldn't find an example which shows how they are extracted and laid over the original sequence by ffplay. I thought that if I can find that out, I could possibly re-arrange the code to extract the MVs to a text file.

I would appreciate any example codes or hints.

Comment: It looks like the same question from stackoverflow: [Motion Vector extraction from encoded video file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993733/motion-vector-extraction-from-encoded-video-file).

Answer (score 4):

I think the following code can help you:
https://github.com/vadimkantorov/mpegflow
The main idea is that you need to decode frames first and query motion frames by calling `av_frame_get_side_data` function.

Answer (score 1):

Try https://github.com/jishnujayakumar/MV-Tractus. This tool will give you motion vectors in the form of JSON for every frame.